# Как в базу данных SQLite Добавить Список из строк

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

Я понимаю что SQLite не поддерживает списки, но каким способом можно это реализовать

Comment: В SQLite? Создаёте текстовое поле, кладёте в него JSON-массив.. чем не список? функции для обработки JSON у SQLite имеются..

Comment: Вообще, подобное делается через связи, где ваш список, это отдельная таблица с данными. Правда я не знаю, грамотно-ли работают связи в SQLite, но вроде как нечто подобное есть. А так да, вам не мешает кто-либо заниматься сериализацией, чтоб ваш список был в виде строки. P.S. Чисто мое IMHO, SQLite уже давно пора положить на полку истории, заменив его, например на LiteDB или нечто подобное, ибо и быстрее, и удобней, да и возможностей больше.